# Run an Asp.Net Core website + a Console app(.Net core) in ONE Docker?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to do a website running under Asp.Net Core.

I was willing to wrap it in a Docker container(mostly for my education ;)), and I was wondering if it would be possible to wrap also a console application, which would continuously until a time to "schedule" some maintenance application?

Thank you

Comment: ASP.Net Core apps are effectively console apps anyway, this is exactly how they work in a Docker environment.

Comment: @DavidG I'm stupid, thank you for the comment, you're totally correct :)